# Crash report for an android library - not to be related to the application iteslf

Tags: android, crash-reports

I'm looking for a crash reporter api, which will work on an sdk that we've been developing, regardless of the app which uses the sdk.

I don't want all the apps that uses our sdk to do any other definitions for this purpose, I want it to be in the background, and **not related the the app's gradle, manifest or Application's onCreate method.**

I've been searching a lot for this, and all the api i found demanding one of the requirements in the paragraph above.

So, here's a list of sdk that i've looked into, all of them require an app definition, which doesn't fit my needs.

1. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android) : Fe, firebase is require to set the gradle dependency in the app level, define the app itself and init the sdk in the application context(which i can handle in the library) :

   ```
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
   ```
2. [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install)
3. [acra](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-and-use-acra-android/en)
4. [New relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-android/get-started/android-installation-configuration)
5. [instabug](https://instabug.com/developers)
6. [apteligent](https://docs.apteligent.com/android/android_install.html)
7. [hockeyapp](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk)

Please don't offer something like 'make all the apps that using the sdk define x,y,z' - this is not the solution i'm looking for.

Comment: [This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any libraries that work the way you want.

However what you could do, is to fill all your outwards facing methods with try/catch(Exception e) and handle the logging yourself. E.g. simply by silently sending an email or by some REST call.

Be sure to throw the exceptions again after sending, so that the implementing app can deal with the failure as well and is not left in a state where it thinks what your lib did worked, when it actually failed.

Comment: tracking a lot of users like this, without any consistency will take forever. thanks though.

Comment: I don't see what prevents you from having consistency and proper tracking (easier with REST than with email I guess). Generate a userId, save it in the preferences and send it together with your logs, (together with library version and whatever else you might need). Of course the harder part is organizing/visualizing it in some meaningful way.

Comment: sounds like re-inventing the wheel. Too much work for a model that's out there for the past few years already.

Comment: That's exactly what it is, but since you haven't found any library that does exactly what you want, unfortunately that's what you'll have to do. If I had to do that I would probably use REST to send the report to my backend together with an anonymous userId and some misc data like version number and what the method input was, put it in a database and query as needed (grouping, sorting, etc). That doesn't sound to bad to me, but I might have missed something.

Comment: @Dus Did you find any crash reporting library?

Comment: @AmanVerma didn't back then, we implemented it ourselves.. but maybe today sometimes is out there :)